# MEF Child Container Module Not Initializing

Tags: module, prism, mef, containers, hierarchy

I have a simple container hierarchy with a parent container which is defined in the Shell MEFBootstrapper using a Directory catalog, and child container(s) which get created off the parent with a distinct catalog.

My child containers also use DirectoryCatalog (different path than parent), and I can see that the container has assembly and part information during runtime.

However, the Initialize() method for the modules located in the child containers are never called.

My goal is to use the child containers as session constructs, allowing the user to create new sessions and toggle between them.  But if I cannot get the constituent modules to initialize (and place their views into the regions), I am kind of stuck.

I had thought to raise an event from my session manager using event aggregator to allow the modules to listen for the event and self-initialize, but that doesn't seem to work either.

i. Why isn't Initialize getting called on modules loaded into a child container
ii. How can I "trigger" Initialize from the container instance (outside of the module context?)  Can you iterate over the assemblies in the container and trigger Initialize that way???

[from MefBootstrapper in shell project]

```
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        ExportProvider ep = this.Container as ExportProvider;
        this.Container.ComposeExportedValue(ep);
```

[from the service that manages my sessions (containers)]

```
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public SessionService(ExportProvider provider)
    {
```

[constructor for new sessions (containers)]

```
    private void Init(ComposablePartCatalog catalog, ExportProvider provider, string name, int callId, bool useContextProxy)
    {
        this._Name = name;
        this._CallID = callId;
        this.startTime = DateTime.Now;
        this.appHost = new CompositionContainer(catalog, new ExportProvider[] { provider });
    }
```

=====

Was asked to include my module code whose initialize method is not called (despite being loaded into the container in question...I can even lazy instantiate the module, but calling Initialize() directly causes the injection operation to fail in the method proper.

```
namespace Module1
{
//, InitializationMode = InitializationMode.OnDemand
[ModuleExport("Module1.ModuleInit", typeof(Module1.ModuleInit))]
public class ModuleInit : IModule
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
    public IServiceLocator _serviceLocator;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ModuleInit(IRegionManager regionManager, IServiceLocator serviceLocator)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        _serviceLocator = serviceLocator;
    }

    #region IModule Members


    public void Initialize()
    {
        // Use View Discovery to automatically display the MasterView when the TopLeft region is displayed.
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.TopLeftRegion, () => _serviceLocator.GetInstance<MasterView>());
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show an example module with an `Initialize` method?

Comment: Sure, pretty simple though, straight from the PRISM template project in VS2010: (see edit)

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded your code and had a look at it. I immediately found the problem. The bootstrapper is actually getting exports thanks to a DirectoryCatalog like this:

```
DirectoryCatalog catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(".");
this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(catalog);
```

This means that you will get the exports from the assemblies in this directory. So you simply need to copy all the the assemblies with the exported types in the directory ".", that is to say the executing directory (Debug/bin).

Just copy Module1 and Module2 in the bin directory and everthing will compose gracefully :)

Actually I found that the post-build events supposed to copy the modules in the bin directory were not working. Maybe because your renamed something. So if you want it automatically copy the assemblies after building just replace the actual post-build event by this one:

```
copy "$(TargetDir)\$(TargetFileName)" "$(TargetDir)\..\..\..\Shell\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\"
```

Comment: Again, thank you for taking the time to look at this.
However, if I put Module1 and Module2 into the root directory, they will be loaded into the initial catalog and in turn will be available from the root CompositionContainer.  My goal (ill-guided perhaps), was to segregate Module1 and Module2 into a child CompositionContainer *only*, so that the root CompositionContainer could *not* satisfy Import requests for those modules...only the child container could.  But I'm starting to think this is just a bad idea, and that I should simply load all my modules into a single catalog/container.

Comment: Yes it is most likely to export all you type in a single place. If what you need is to initialize your modules when needed you can delay loading by configuring the modules as OnDemand.

Answer (score 1):

I already had this problem many times and resolving it is really simple.

Remove the constructor from the your module. Prism modules are not activated the same way it does for classical exported types, therefore modules cannot use ImportingConstructor to import the services you need. Instead intitialize them with the ServiceLocator within the Initialize method.

This will work:

```
[ModuleExport("Module1.ModuleInit", typeof(Module1.ModuleInit))]
public class ModuleInit : IModule
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _regionManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>();

        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.TopLeftRegion, () => _serviceLocator.GetInstance<MasterView>());
    }
}
```

I also think that this behavior is kind of disturbing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but even with those changes, the Initialize method simply isn't getting called.  When a (child) container is created outside of the MEFBootstrapper, with no ConfigureContainer method getting called, how do the modules within that container's catalog get Initialized?  I know I'm missing something pretty obvious here.

Comment: What do you mean by "created"? Is it composed within a container or is it simply instantiated?

Comment: I wrote created with respect to the child container(s).  They are created using the following:
    
   this.appHost = new CompositionContainer(catalog, new ExportProvider[] { provider });

Comment: If you wanna intialize this module from the Bootstrapper, then override the ConfigureAggregate method and call this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(InitModule).Assembly)); If your assembly is in a directory, use the DirectoryCatalog instead. If you want to initialize your module outside of the Booostrapper, then call ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ModuleInit>() to compose the module. But if this stilt not resolves your problem, can you provide a sample project so I can reproduce your issue and help you on that?

Comment: Link to zip of sample:
https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=b354172beb17c34d&resid=B354172BEB17C34D!154
See if you can get the first session instance's container to actually load Module1 and Module2 and display them.

Comment: I replied in a new answer. You should edit your original question ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem where my modules Initialize() method was not being called... I realized I had left off the "override" keyword on my Initialize method that was declared virtual in the Module base class that all of my modules inherit from... added "override" and it worked!